Parsing Error: Cannot Find Module '@babel/preset-env' in React App Using react-scripts
I'm encountering a persistent issue when trying to start my React app. The error I receive is:
Parsing error: Cannot find module '@babel/preset-env'
Require stack:
- /path/to/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js
- /path/to/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/index.js
- /path/to/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/index.js
...

I'm using react-scripts and eslint, and the error suggests that the @babel/preset-env module is missing. However, I don't explicitly use a babel.config.js file in my project. My package.json contains the following dependencies:
{
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^7.32.0"
  }
}

I've tried the following solutions but haven't had success:

Reinstalling dependencies (npm install and npm ci).
Manually installing @babel/preset-env using npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-env.
Clearing the npm cache (npm cache clean --force).
Downgrading and upgrading Node.js (currently using Node v20.15.0 with nvm).

I use concurrently to start both a backend and frontend service, and this is the script that triggers the issue:
"start": "concurrently \"npm run start --prefix backend\" \"npm run start --prefix frontend\""

The backend works fine, but the frontend fails to compile with the error above.
Any guidance on how to resolve this error would be greatly appreciated!

The "react-scripts": "4.0.3" in your package.json is 4 years old so have a look at the engines property and dependencies property of that package.json here. You might have to downgrade your Node.js version more so try 18LTS, 16LTS or even 14LTS which can be found on previous releases.
